# <rich:suggestionbox> Tag Library supports namespace: http://richfaces.org/rich, but no tag was defined for name: suggestionbox

Tags: jsf, richfaces

Why am I getting this error? I am using richfaces 4.5.12. Here's my source:-

```
    <h:panelGroup>
          <h:inputText id="pointsNameInput" value="#{whitelistConfig.pointsName}" />
          <rich:suggestionbox id="suggestionBoxId" for="pointsNameInput" 
                suggestionAction="#{whitelistConfig.fetchPointsNames}" var="result"
                width="120px"
                height="150px"
                nothingLabel="No points name matched" 
                usingSuggestObjects="true">
                <h:column>
                    <h:outputText value="#{result.value}" />
                </h:column> </rich:suggestionbox> </h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's pretty simple. There is no `rich:suggestionbox` in RF 4.5.12.

Check out [VDL](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/4.5.X/4.5.12.Final/vdldoc/) or [showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org).

Answer (score 0):

As @Emil said, it doesn´t exist anymore.

What you need to use now is `rich:autocomplete`:

http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/index.html?rich/autocomplete.html